# Mutual mouse pointer between two computers

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, synergy

Is it possible to have one mouse pointer for two computer systems?

It's like dual screening, but each screen is assigned to a different computer.

The OP of the indicated "answered before" asks for a hardware switch solution, this is totaly different.

Comment: Perhaps you should have specified a software solution was required. Have you looked at Synergy? http://synergy-foss.org/

Comment: It's already answered, but they tagged it as duplicate and linked it to a different type of question (as I believe in my opinion). Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you want is provided by [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) which is free and supported by donation.

You run the software on two or more computers which are close to each other, and as you move the mouse off of one screen, it jumps onto the next screen.  Also the keyboard controls the computer where the mouse is currently.

It works on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

**OR**

> [Mouse without Borders](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460) is a product that makes you the captain of your
>   computer fleet by allowing you to control up to four computers from a
>   single mouse and keyboard. This means that with Mouse without Borders
>   you can copy text or drag and drop files across computers.

It is only for Windows.

Comment: I used synergy as a keyword and I found out that microsoft provides "Mouse withought Borders"! I don't know the cons yet... but seems legit for windows-windows machines. Synergy is cool as well for multi platform enviroments as I see.

Comment: It seems that Synergy is no longer available for free?